# Why doesn't my crontab job find the correct file path?

Tags: cron, cron-task

```
echo "Enter base root directory ..."
cd ./base
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
echo "Downloading resources ..."
python3 ./util/fetch.py -o ./  downloadResources

echo "Exit from base and enter the upper level directory ..."
cd ..
python3 ./test/data_poster.py

echo "done ..."
```

I have a crontab job as listed above(auto_run.sh). What it does:

1. In the root directory of the current project, to enter the base/ subdirectory
2. under base/, it download some resources files
3. The it exited from the base/ directory and in the root directory, to run 'data_poster.py'

The problem occurs. In the log of the crontab, it complains that:

```
python3: can't open file './util/fetch.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python3: can't open file './test/data_poster.py
```

Why can't the cronjob execute the python script in both cases? The path to the two scripts are right. If I just run 'sh auto_run.sh' without using cronjob, it works all right.

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly set up your environment in the crontab script. That's because cron runs from a non-interactive, non-login shell.

When your cron script runs cd ./base, there is no "." (current directory) as there was no login shell to set one.  Use full paths.

See [This question on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables) for more info.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly set up your environment in the crontab script"?

Comment: Gary_w, can you add more details to your answer? It's too short.

Comment: @marlon ARGH my edit wasn't saved.  I'll try again.